# Why does $1 \cdot 0=0$ not stand?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

A set $G$  together with an operation $*$ is called group when it satisfies the following properties:

1. $a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c,  \forall a,b,c \in G$
2. $ \exists e \in G: e*a=a*e=a, \forall a \in G$
3. $\forall a \in G \exists a' \in G: a'*a=e=a*a'$
   $$$$
   $$(\mathbb{Z}, \cdot ) \text{ is not a group}$$

The property $(1)$ is satisfied.

For the property$(2)$ we take $e=1$. But while $1 \cdot a = a \cdot 1 =a, \forall a \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0 \}$, it does not stand that $1 \cdot 0=0$.

I haven't understood why $1 \cdot 0=0$ does not stand...Could you explain it to me?

Comment: It is not (2) that fails here. $1$ is indeed the "$e$" for this operation.

Comment: 1*0 = 0 does stand. The problem is that 0 is not invertible. For every integer a, 0*a = 0. But for (3) to be satisfied we need, in particular, a number x such that x*0 = 1. And there's no such x, obviously.

Answer (score 7):

property 2. is OK, indeed 1 works as $e$ here.

It's property 3 that fails: if there an $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x \cdot 2 = 1$?

Comment: So it fails because the inverse of each element except from $1$ and $-1$ is not an integer... Thank you!!! :-)

Answer (score 5):

There isn't any failure in terms in property $(2)$. $1$ is certainly the identity, and it *does stand* that $0\times 1 = 1\times 0 = 0$.

But, zero creates another problem:

Consider property $(3)$ asserting that for every element in a group, its inverses exists *and is **in** the group, too.* This is where things "go bad" for $0$, and essentially every element in $\mathbb Z$ that is not $-1$ or $1$:

Is there any $a$ such that $a \cdot 0 = 0\cdot a = e = 1$?

Is there any $a \in \mathbb Z$ such that $a \cdot 3 = 3\cdot a = 1$?

Comment: Ok!!! Thank you for your answer!!! :-)

Comment: You're welcome, Mary!

Answer (score 4):

The property $(2)$ is satisfied for $(\mathbb Z, \cdot)$, because for $e=1$, you have that $1\cdot 0 = 0\cdot 1 = 0$.

Now, if property $(1)$ and $(2)$ both hold, that leaves only one suspect...

Comment: Ok! The property $(3)$ does not hold... Thank you!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not everything has an inverse in $\mathbb{Z}$ (property 3). For example, there is no element of $\mathbb{Z}$ which you can multiply with $2$ to get the multiplicative identity $1$.

Comment: Ahaa! Ok!! Isn't it that only $1$ has an inverse in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: $(-1)*(-1) = 1$.

Comment: Yes, you're right!!! Thanks a lot!!! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Property (2) indeed holds, the problem is Property (3) in the case of $a=0$.

Comment: But in $\mathbb{Z}$ only $a=1$ satisfies the property $(3)$. Right?  What do you mean that the problem is the Property $(3)$ in the case of $a=0$??

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, in $Z$ only $a=1$ satisfies (3).